# How to find time of high frequency noise in an audio wav / raw file using Python?

Tags: python, audio, scipy, fft

I have an audio clip, and I want to detect when a certain (high pitch) noise occurs. I don't know anything about FFT, how do I return the audio frame at which the noise occurs (I was thinking frequency trigger)?

Comment: what stops you from learning something about FFT ?

Comment: Nothing, just not sure if I needed to. If someone responds "you have to learn FFT to do this", then I'll learn it.

Comment: you asked for it: you have to learn FFT to do this!! =)

Comment: i figured it out, don't have to know FFT to use the library

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have "scipy" there: You can [compute a spectrogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.spectrogram.html) to get frequencies over time for your sample (which you can load with [`wavfile.read`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html).

You can then plot the spectrogram and figure out what the frequency you're looking for is.

Then

- either loop over the spectrogram data itself to find the time where there's suitably strong signal in that frequency, or
- [filter your original signal](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.4.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.butter.html#scipy.signal.butter) first (a bandpass filter would be best) and then find the overall intense bits.

Comment: Is there a way I can iterate over the times, and find the frequency at that time? I'm confused why the shape of the spectrogram is (frequency, # of times)

Why are there so many values for each time, and vice versa?

The plot looks good though